# Can't overwrite a file on a sd card on an intel edison

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard, overwrite, intel-edison

I am writing to a file on an sd card on an intel edison. 
I use 
    File f = sd.open("filename.txt", FILE_WRITE);
    f.write("something");
    f.close();'
In a loop. Instead of overwriting what was previously on filename.txt, which i assumed to be the default, it is just appended to the bottom.

Does anyone know how to overwrite the file without deleting it every time?
Even if it's some sort of function that clears the file then writes to it each time.

Thanks

Comment: You can use [FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)) and set append flag to false.  I haven't tested it yet hence posting in comment.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm a little confused about how would I use this with the sd card? @Naveed